# Is there a definition of the existential quantifier which does not imply the axiom of choice?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, formal-systems

The definition of the existential quantifer given in Bourbaki's *Theory of Sets* is

$$(\exists x)R \iff (\tau_x(R)\mid x)R.$$

Here $x$ is a letter, $R$ is a relation, and $(\tau_x(R)\mid x)R$ means substitute $\tau_x(R)$ for $x$ in $R$. We interpret $x$ as a set, $R$ as expressing a property of $x$, and $\tau_x(R)$ as a distinguished object with the property $R$. Hence "there exists $x$ such that $R$" is equivalent to "$\tau_x(R)$ satisfies $R$".

In particular, if $A$ is a set, $(\exists x)(x \in A)$ is equivalent to $\tau_x(x \in A) \in A$. If $f$ is a surjection of $A$ onto a set $B$, then for all $y \in B$ there exists $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. Therefore, we can define a right inverse $g$ of $f$ by 
$$g(y) = \tau_x(x \in A \text{ and } y = f(x))$$ 
for $y \in B$. This implies the axiom of choice.

Is there a definition of the existential quantifier which does not imply the axiom of choice? I am only familiar with Bourbaki's definition.

Comment: AFAIK (and I know very, very little), the existential quantifier can be taken as an element of the language of logic. Therefore, for set theory, it is already given. Also, it may be relevant to note that Wikipedia says that "Logic is treated minimally.[22]" in Bourbaki. 
I would take this comment as an idea of a layman, however. Most likely more adequate people will come and adress your question shortly.

Comment: Bourbaki's system, as I recall vaguely, is peculiar in that it is somewhat difficult to separate logical issues and set-theoretic issues. What causes the axiom of choice to be true here is the interplay of the logical system chosen with $\tau$ in it and the properly set-theoretic axioms. The fact that $\exists$ is chosen as an abbreviation for something involving $\tau$ isn't the problem in itself. There is a widely accepted system for the formalization of proofs which is different from Bourbaki's. It is explained for instance in Cori and Lascar's book, in Chapter 4.

Comment: More precisely, the relevant feature of Bourbaki's system probably lies in the class of permissible conditions used to define a set, in their comprehension axiom. In the standard approach to set theory, these conditions cannot be formulated using anything like $\tau$.

Comment: @David So the axiom of choice is not a theorem in that system (together with the Zermelo-Frankel axioms)?

Comment: No, the axiom of choice is not a theorem in ZF (unless we are all mistaken in believing that ZF is even consistent).

Comment: *Existence* of your $g$ as a set isn't guaranteed, and requires essentially the Axiom of Choice. Just for background, Bourbaki didn't invent $\tau$ operator or its rules. It first figured in one of Hilbert's systems, where it was denoted by $\sigma$ and stood for "selector".

Answer (score 1):

The symbols for quantifiers used in [Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki), [Elements of Mathematics : Theory of sets](https://books.google.it/books?id=7eclBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA36) (1968 - French ed. 1958), see page 20 and page 36, are derived from [The Epsilon Calculus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epsilon-calculus/) developed by David Hilbert during the 20s [with $\tau_x$ in place of $εx$].

The syntax of the $ε$ *symbol* is:

> if $A$ is a formula and $x$ is a variable, $εx \ A$ is a *term*

with the axiom (Hilbert's “transfinite axiom”) :

> $A(x) → A(εx A)$.
>
> The intended interpretation is that $εx \ A$ denotes some $x$ satisfying $A$, if there is one.

Quantifiers can defined as follows:

> > $∃x A(x) ≡ A(εx A)$
> >
> > $∀x A(x) ≡ A(εx (¬A)).$

---

Of course, in classical logic, the usual quantifiers are interdefineable.